# VueRouter is not defined

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

I have a laravel project and want use Vue.js for frontend. But i have never used 
something more complicated than jquery. I can't run vue-router.

In my app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('./vue-router');
require('./routes');

window.Vue = require('vue');
     const app = new Vue({
     el: '#app',
});
```

Then i copy code vue-router from https://router.vuejs.org/en/installation.html

In my routes.js

```
const router = new VueRouter();

var App = Vue.extend({});

router.start(App, '#app');
```

And when i try open page in console i see next : "VueRouter is not defined"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to tell Vue to use VueRouter using the method `Vue.use()` first. So, do:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

# add this code
Vue.use(VueRouter)

var router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {path: 'home', component: homeComponent} 
  ]
})
```

UPDATED:

First install vue-router using

```
npm install --save vue-router
```

Then import and use it like

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
```

Then use it in vue

```
Vue.use(VueRouter)
```

Then define your routes:

```
const routes = [
 {path: '/', component: SomeComponent}
]
```

then initialize the router and pass it the routes

```
var router = new VueRouter({
  routes: routes,
  mode: 'history'
})
```

Pass router to vuejs then profit :)

```
new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  router: router
})
```

Comment: ok, thanks. i did

window.VueRouter = require('vue-router');
Vue.use(VueRouter);

but now i have error Uncaught TypeError: VueRouter is not a constructor

Comment: Leave `window.VueRouter` just do `VueRouter`

Comment: can you do `import VueRouter from 'vue-router'` instead of `require` ..

Comment: import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);

now  "VueRouter is not defined" again

Comment: Do you even have VueRouter installed? check your `package.json`

Comment: Why is it in your `devDependencies`? It should be inside `dependencies` instead. You need to install it as `npm install --save vue-router`. Anyway, please don't use require ... just import it. and try again

Comment: I did npm install --save vue-router, after this i did import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter); and then http://joxi.ru/krDLndPSEn8Rzr

but VueRouter is not defined

Comment: Check my updated response. I really hope you are using webpack or something like that. Otherwise, if you are not `import`, `require` won't work. Try the guide I gave you,

Comment: You said it works before so you must have modified something. Please check and redo my updated guide

Comment: I thought it worked because the console gave an error "SomeComponent is not defined" and i thought that VueRouter is defined, but when i replace "SomeComponent" on path to file, console gave old error "VueRouter is not defined"

Comment: Lets start again. I have package.json - http://joxi.ru/brRa073uJb5zQA and app.js - http://joxi.ru/Dr8dQbGF4bxWvr . In my packages.js i have http://joxi.ru/ZrJQ736f97qz6A . In my routes. js http://joxi.ru/8AnxgZ4sjvYGgm but i have error "VueRouter is not defined"

Comment: After I transferred all the code in app.js everything worked

Comment: Now I get the problem, please first do `npm install --save vue` second  remove `require('packages')` from you app.js (line 22) third: put all the code from `packages.js` into app.js (on line 22) fourth: remove line 5-8 in routes.js and put it in app.js (after line 23) and in route.js put `export default routes` after on line 4.

Comment: @Виктор Let me know if this did not work for you, so I can remove my answer

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to use the `Vue.use` method, here's how you do it:

```
Vue.use(VueRouter) // use the imported router as the parameter.
```